# Datatables pagination event not firing with number buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

We're using Datatables on our project and I've got the following code, taken from [here](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page), to fire events when the page changes with Datatables pagination:

```
$("#myTable").on('page.dt', function () {
    console.log('next ...');
});
```

I have the pagination control rendered like below:

[image]

The event handler above fires when I click on the 'Previous' or the 'Next' buttons but clicking on the page numbers doesn't. Anyone have any ideas about this behaviour?

**Update**:

This is the initialization code for DataTables:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    dataTable = $("#myTable").DataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'p><'span6'f>>t",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap-leftAligned",
    });
});
```

Comment: you are using `DataTable` or `dataTable` function?

Comment: @user2352577L DataTable()

Comment: can you provide more code and datatable version? because it works for me in my projects. This function allows the version above  1.10

Comment: I've added the code. I'm using the latest version. The method must be compatible because it's firing with the 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons.

Comment: change the `sPaginationType` => `pagingType` and `sDom` => `dom`. You are using the old coding style of old `dataTable` in new `DataTable`  which may cause this problem.

Comment: @user2352577L Thanks. Tried that but that didn't work.

Comment: did you include `buttons.bootstrap.js` and `dataTables.buttons.js`? and try to remove `dom` and `paging type`. paging type does not include `bootstrap-leftAligned` in `DataTable`. https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType

Comment: @user2352577L `bootstrap-leftAligned` is an extension to get that styling you see.

Comment: if you want to get the bootstrap stlye, you must include the bootstrap css and javascript. install instruction: https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap and not using the bootstrap-leftAligned in pagingType